# LCS dynamic programming using one dimensional array

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am trying to do dynamic programming for finding length of LCS. I have used two dimensional array for that. But for a large string it gives runtime error due to memory overflow. Please tell me How should I do it in one dimensional array to avoid memory constrains.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
 #include<string.h> 
 using namespace std;
int max(int a, int b);
int lcs( string X, string Y, int m, int n )
{
   int L[m+1][n+1];
   int i, j;
   for (i=0; i<=m; i++)
   {
     for (j=0; j<=n; j++)
     {
       if (i == 0 || j == 0)
         L[i][j] = 0;

       else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
         L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1;

       else
         L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
     }
   }

   return L[m][n];
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

int main()
{
  string X;
  string Y;
  cin>>X>>Y;
  int m = X.size();
  int n = Y.size();

  printf("Length of LCS is %d\n", lcs( X, Y, m, n ) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [OT] `int L[m+1][n+1];` use variable length array **extension**, prefer to use `std::vector`.

Comment: vector is also giving runtime error for input string around 500k

Comment: Tricky; you probably need to adapt [Hirshberg’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm) to solve this. It’s feasible, but definitely much more complex than the simple LCS algorithm (EDIT: Ah, you’re only interested in the length, not the actual subsequence; that’s much easier, see Sergei’s answer). Unrelatedly, you *definitely* need to use `vector` instead of variable-length arrays; also, switch on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` on GCC and clang) and make your compiler pedantic (`-pedantic` on GCC and clang).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the recursion in `lcs` only uses the last two rows of the `L` matrix. Thus you can easily rewrite your solution to use O(N) memory.

Here's a [good article](http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

two dimensional array is fiction anyway, it's still one dimensional array, so calculate indexes on your own, ie: so your array int L[(n+1)*(m+1)] and index of L[i][j] =  L[i*(n+1)+j]